# random numbers in a row for keno game

Tags: java, oop

I develop a keno game and i am confused on how I can take the random numbers for example from the console and place them to the textfield. I tried to make it with ArrayList or Array but it was wrong.
Below you can find my code.
Thank you for your help!!

```
import java.util.Random;  
public class Game {

    private final int RANDOMNUMBER = 80;
    private int prob;
    String k;
    String res;
    public void rNumbers() {
        for (int x = 0; x <= 12; x++) {
            Random d = new Random();
            prob = d.nextInt(RANDOMNUMBER) + 0;
            System.out.println(prob);
        }
        k= Integer.toString(prob);
    }

    public String toString(){
        return ""+prob;
    }
}
```

the other class

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GuiKino extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private JPanel contentPanel;
    private JPanel otherPanel;

    private JTextField text;
    private JButton rollButton;

    Game t = new Game();

    private JLabel[] a = new JLabel[80];

    GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout();

    public GuiKino() {

        this.setTitle("Kino");

        // Create panels
        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        contentPanel = new JPanel();
        otherPanel = new JPanel();

        this.contentPanel = (JPanel) getContentPane();

        contentPanel.add(otherPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        contentPanel.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10));
        otherPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 4));

        text = new JTextField("");

        rollButton = new JButton("Klirosi");
        rollButton.addActionListener(this);

        otherPanel.add(text);
        otherPanel.add(rollButton);

        for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
            a[j] = new JLabel("");

            a[j].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        }

        //cell numbers
        for(int l=0; l<a.length; l++){
            a[l].setText(""+l);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            mainPanel.add(a[i]);
            }
        }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == rollButton) {
            t.rNumbers();
            text.setText(t.toString());
            text.getText();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly go wrong? Can you make [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Do u want to show a series of random number ?

Comment: Exactly I want a series of random numbers

Comment: The problem is that when I execute the method rNumbers() to my console, then I have 12 random numbers. When I try to "parse" them to the JTextField I get only the last random number and not the other 11.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to obtain the random number by using the random() method from the Math class [See the docs here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html).

   2. Using the previos recomendation I think that you can created a method that fill an array with the generated random number and them you can ethier printed on the console or placed in the gui.

I hope that I had helped you.

Pd. Sorry for  my english I'm Venezuela.

Comment: thank you for your answer! My problem is not how to get random numbers but how to input them to my gui. I have tried with ArrayList and Array but I didn't make it. When I run my program and I make a System.out.print, then all the numbers are displayed but when I call the method text.setText, only the last number is displayed. If you have any idea then I would be really appreiciate to discuss it.

Comment: @MichalisTripolitsiotis now I understand better, the problem is that you only stored the last generated number in the prob attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can get some random numbers in a certain range with `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(origin, bound);`, origin being the inclusive bottom number, and bound being the exclusive upper number.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. Secondly, my problem is not the range of random numbers but how to execute to the JTextField area. In addition I don't know with this solution if I have to add this code line that you wrote to the setter or the getter of the JTextField or if I have to change the whole method rNumbers().

Comment: @MichalisTripolitsiotis This line of code returns one integer each time it is run. I would suggest declaring a string to hold the contents of the text field, and concatenating each random number to this string in a for loop. You can then update the contents of the Textfield with the string.

Answer (score 0):

Guys I have found a solution. I made a new variable `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();`into my Game Class and then I used the `sb.append("-");` and `sb.append(prob);` into my method `rNumbers()`and worked!